# Send variable content to other (unrelated) component Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, angular15

I am trying to send the content of a variable to a different component, so I can use that value in the other component (both components are a different page and not related to eachother, but I don't need to display the variable content on any page, I just need to use the variable content on the other typescript component). I can't get it to work properly with any tutorials and I just don't know what to do anymore.

[This is the file layout (need to send variable content from week component to day component)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qfft.png)

The following code is located in p1_week-chart.component.ts:

```
else if (chart.data.labels[activeEls[0].index] == "Wednesday") {
          this.dayClicked = new Date(this.today);
          this.dayClicked.setDate(this.dayClicked.getDate() + 2);
          console.log(this.dayClicked);
          //want to send content of this.dayClicked to other component (p1_day-chart.component.ts)
```

extra info: I don't need anything in html, I just need typescript for this part

Help is much appreciated!

(I tried a lot of different solutions that I found online including BehaviorSubject, but I just simply can't get it to send the content of this.dayClicked to the p1_day-chart.component.ts. I see that some other people asked the same kind of question here, but I looked through a lot of them and I still wasn't able to get it to work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it to work:

```
//Service:
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedParamsService {

  message: string
  
  constructor() { }
  setMessage(data)
  {
    this.message=data
  }
  getMessage() {
    return this.message
  }

}

//Sending component:
message: any;

 constructor(private sharedParams: SharedParamsService){}

//when the action happens and variable needs to be send
this.sharedParams.setMessage(this.dayClicked);


//Receiving component:
message: any;

constructor(private sharedParams: SharedParamsService){}

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.message = this.sharedParams.getMessage(); 
}
//now this.message is the correct variable that I sent and that I will use in this component later on
```

Thank you for your answers everyone, really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

If components are unrelated a simple way to achieve what you want is by emitting the variable from one component to an other. For this you need a service like:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/internal/Subscription';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedParamsService {

  invokeFirstComponentFunction = new EventEmitter();
  subsVar: Subscription;

  constructor() { }

  onUpdateEnv(key, val) {
    var toEmit = [key, val]
    this.invokeFirstComponentFunction.emit(toEmit);
  }
}
```

In the component in which you emit the variable:

- import SharedParamsService
- declare in constructor private sharedParams: SharedParamsService
  then in code, where you have the variable ready to emit:

> this.sharedParams.onUpdateEnv("Day clicked", this.dayClicked);

In the component who needs to receive the variable:

- import SharedParamsService
- declare in constructor private sharedParams: SharedParamsService

> this.sharedParams.subsVar =
> this.sharedParams.invokeFirstComponentFunction .subscribe((emitted) =>
> {
> if (emitted[0] == "Day clicked") {
> this.dayClickedReceived = emitted[1];
> } });

Answer (score 0):

Question based on what you said @s_frix,

Component who needs to receive currently has this:

```
import { SharedParamsService } from 'src/app/components/charts/testcomponent';

//Other not important code left out obviously between this

//if dayClickedReceived: any; is added and console logged in ngOnInit() it will show "undefined"

  constructor(private http : HttpClient,
    private globalvars: GlobalvarsService, //not important
           private adapter: DateAdapter<any>, //not important 
    private datePipe: DatePipe, //not important
  private sharedParams: SharedParamsService) { console.log(this.urlDate); }
//ignore the console log that's for something else
              
  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.sharedParams.subsVar = this.sharedParams.invokeFirstComponentFunction .subscribe((emitted) => { if (emitted[0] == "Day clicked") { this.dayClickedReceived = emitted[1]; } });
}
```

Getting error: "Property 'dayClickedReceived' does not exist..."
And if I create it and console log it later it comes back as "undefined" when I switch to the page that needs to receive. (when I sent the event I do actually get the correct console log directly, but that's not usefull, because I need to use it on the other page and when I go to that page dayClickedReceived is undefined again)

Basically what needs to happen is when I am on the page that needs to send the variable and make it run, then I click on the other page (that needs to receive it) and there I want to use the content of the variable

Comment: Did you emit correctly the variable in your "sender component"? It's ok to declare dayClickedReceived of course

Comment: Yeah on the sender component I get the console.log from the receiving component and see that it works, but when I got to the actual receiving component on the website the console.log is undefined

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question. Do not post questions on someone else's question, open up your own question instead.

Comment: It wasn't a question on someone else's question. He posted a solution and I had a question for him based on his solution, because it didn't work. Commenting doesn't have the code markup (and doesn't allow enough characters), which is why I didn't use the comment, but used a post instead. @FiniteLooper